# Proyecto Asp.Net al subir a servidor deja de funcionar

Tags: c#, asp.net, servidor

Al trabajar con mi proyecto localmente funciona a la perfección, pero cuando intento subirlo a mi servidor ocurre algún problema yme marca el siguiente error 
Alguna sugerencia ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás deba incluir mas información sobre el tipo de proyecto que esta realizando. En general creo que es un problemas de rutas. Yo para evitar ese tipo de problemas siempre trabajo en mi servidor local http://localhost y no en el de desarrollo de Visual Studio. de esa manera cuando paso entre ambientes no tengo mayor problema por el tema de rutas.

Comment: De pronto me pasaba algo parecido.
cuando se trabaja local el proyecto compila bien por que tiene bien configurado el Framework. Cuando se sube el proyecto al servidor, el pool del IIS tiene una versión por defecto, de pronto puede ser que no corresponda a la versión que estás trabajando localmente. Intenta creando otro pool o modificando el que ya tiene asignado.

Answer (score 0):

El error dice que no encuentra tu página master `Web.master` en la ruta indicada.
Revisa que tengas publicada correctamente esa página master en la ruta especificada: `~/PaginaBase/Web.Master`